# how to write an excel formula in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in vba. I have an excel formula that I want to write it as vba code. But I have a problem with that. I do not know how to do that. Can anybody help me?
here is the formula:

`IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(G$6:G$8,B6),G$6:G$8),"")`

Actually I have some keywords in column G from sheet2 and I want to search them in column B from sheet1, which contains text. If there is any match I want that vba code returns the matched keyword in a column (for example D) in first sheet, if not leaves the corresponding cell empty.

I do not know how to do that. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does this function evaluate in the Worksheet? I don't think you can use a Range argument in the `Search` function.

Comment: Additionally, the formula you include does not really match the description of what you think the formula does. I.e., nowhere in the formula do you refer to Sheet1 or Sheet2...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a stab at this even though the description you provide does not seem to match the function you provide.

I use the `IsError` function with the `Application.Match` first to check if the `lookup_value` is found in the Range("B:B") on Sheet1.

```
Dim lookup_value as String ' the value you're searching for.'
Dim found_value as String ' the value to return if a match is found.'

lookup_value = "edit this value!"  '<~~ This is the value you're searching for. Edit as needed.'

If Not IsError(Application.Match(lookup_value, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B"),False) Then
    'If the above does not yield an error, then set the found_value based on VLOOKUP.'
    found_value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup_value, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:D"),2,False)
Else:
    'If the MATCH function returns an error, set the found_value = vbNullString.
    found_value = vbNullString
End If
```

From this result, you can simply set a cell value to the result of the function, `found_value`.

`ActiveCell.Value = found_value` or `Range("A1").Value = found_value`, etc.

Comment: `VLoopup`? :D Also I noticed that you started using comments like `<~~` ;)

Comment: Ah! Typo!  I very much like the `<~~` :)

Comment: [offtopic]Aha.. It's just that I have been using that for 8 years... That's how I identify my code on the net :P[offtopic]

Comment: + 1 I also think the user wants this. BTW Do you know that instead of `IsError(Application.Match(lookup_value, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B"),False)` you can actually use a simple `countif` to check if the values is there in the other column or not? Something like `If Not Application.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B"), lookup_value) = 0 Then`

Comment: Yes you could also use `CountIf`. I use the `Application.Match` function though, since that method can also be used on Array variables.